# PHP system call function does not properly export variables

Tags: php, bash, apache

I'm using task-spooler to queue up some video encoding tasks (See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/tsp.1.html and http://vicerveza.homeunix.net/~viric/soft/ts/)

In order to select a specific queue (rather than the default per-user queue), the binary requires that you set an environment variable pointing to a socket. In my case: `TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket`. Then running `tsp` shows the status of that specific queue.

This command works in the terminal, as any user: `export TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket ; tsp`

I want to create a web-based status utility that shows this status. Using php on apache2, however, calling a bash script with `exec()` with that same exact command does not work. Nor does `putenv('TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket'); echo exec('tsp');` I've alse tried `` echo `export TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket ; tsp` ``

Running `passthru('whoami')` on the server shows that it's running as user `www-root`, the apache server user. If I log in as that user and run the command, it works fine as expected.

Interestingly, if I run the php interactive shell (`php -a`), I can do any of the above php code and it works just fine, so it seems to be some interaction with apache.

This is all running on Ubuntu 17.10 with PHP 7.1.11 on Apache 2.4.27

Comment: Does the script begin with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Does it work if you split it into two statements: `TS_SOCKET=...` followed by `export TS_SOCKET`

Comment: when you say you "call the script from PHP" I assume you are doing so via some web server request? If so, that's a different user. You can see what user is currently running with `passthru("whoami")`

Comment: Also, have you considered modifying the script so you can supply the TS_SOCKET value is a command line parameter?

Comment: You haven't put enough code to know for sure, but you should try using `PHP`'s `putenv('TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket');` before `exec()` or what ever. depending on what `reencode` needs access to you may need to set the `PATH` the same way.

Comment: So `reencode` is a bash script that calls `tsp` (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man1/tsp.1.html) and passes some ffmepg commands.


@Barmar the script works fine from a terminal; it has a shebang, and splitting the export doesn't help

Comment: @S.Imp the script is user agnostic. the reason I need to pass the environment variable is because its required by the `tsp` binary to specify a socket to use (otherwise it uses a default one in the current users home directory). It could be user related, as I do have a system user for my apache server with disabled login, but in theory as long as I set the environment variable and call `tsp` from php, bypassing my script entirely, I should get the desired output, which I don't.


@hcoat Tried `putenv()` then `exec('tsp')`, but that doesn't work either

Comment: I also tried logging in as the web server user and running the command from the terminal. That works just fine. It's just an issue with php...

Comment: I think you need to post the code of the shell script.

Comment: A simplified case doesn't work either. From a terminal, `export TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket ; tsp` works as any user. Running that command from php `exec()` or using `putenv()` then `exec()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Kayson Barmar is right. It would be helpful if you modified your OP to show more detail about the commands you are running. Logging in as web server user and running things just fine sounds encouraging. Perhaps your server has su_exec installed? In which case each PHP script it runs may run as a different users, depending on where the PHP script lives, etc. I would again refer you to `passthru("whoami")` to identify the name of the user that is running.

Comment: @S.Imp thanks. updated OP to be more clear and with the requested info. php is running as www-root, which I logged into and tested the command on. The most interesting thing is that running the php interactive shell outside apache does not have this problem...

Comment: It may happen that the value of the `PATH` env var in the apache process makes `tsp` resolve to a different executable. Check this hypothesis with `passthru("which tsp")`.

Comment: @Leon just checked and its pointing to the right executable

Comment: @Kayson OK, is there any indication that the `tsp` process is at all executed? Does it exit with an error or it simply doesn't produce any output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't the setting of the environment variable, but accessing the socket. Since apache is running through systemd, it has an isolated `/tmp` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345122/why-php-can-not-see-tmp-files) that is not the same as the `/tmp` where I was putting the socket. Moving the location made everything work just fine!

Comment: Kudos for figuring it out and posting the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this simple test case seems to work via apache + mod_php (7.0)

```
<?php

header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$out = [];
exec('SOME_VAR=FOO && echo $SOME_VAR', $out);
// works too: exec('export SOME_VAR=FOO && echo $SOME_VAR', $out);
var_dump($out);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "FOO"
}
```

In your case this would be

```
<?php

header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$out = [];
exec('TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket && tsp', $out);
// also try: exec('export TS_SOCKET=/tmp/reencode.socket && tsp', $out);
var_dump($out);
```